# SQL: Выбрать по новому номеру, если существует

Tags: mysql, sql

Добрый день, господа.

Имеется база данных, к примеру:

```
id | number | new_number | old_number | status
1  |  123   |   1234     |            | archive
2  |  1234  |            |    123     | active
```

Вопрос в том, как в SQL (Mysql) при поиске по `number` определить что существует новый номер – `new_number` и выбрать запись с новым номером, а не со старым

Comment: А вы выберите `(number=123 or old_number=123) and status='active'`

Comment: @mike Всё гениальное просто! Спасибо. Пожалуйста, напишите "как ответ" и я отмечу его как правильный :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select * from TableX
 where (number=123 or old_number=123) and status='active'
```